# is there a commenter parameter for issues via the GitHub API?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

The GitHub page for web-interactive issue filtering describes [commenter](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commenter) and an [involved](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-in-an-issue-or-pull-request) filters.

However, the [GitHub issues API page](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) lists the following parameters, which don't seem to include commenter:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
|   Name    |       Type        |
+-----------+-------------------+
| milestone | integer or string |
| state     | string            |
| assignee  | string            |
| creator   | string            |
| mentioned | string            |
| labels    | string            |
| sort      | string            |
| direction | string            |
| since     | string            |
+-----------+-------------------+
```